# Add background image to a button in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add the image to a button once its clicked using jquery.I am unable to add an image.

Here is jquery code

```
$('#b2').click(function(){
alert("b2 am called"); 
$(this).addClass("bg1");
});
```

Here is css

```
.bg1 
{
background-image: url(info.jpg);   
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
border: none;    
}

input#b2
{
position:absolute;
left:370px;
top:130px;
width:90px; /*same as the height*/
height:90px;
}
```

Here is Html code

```
<div id="level_1"class="Level1"> 
<input type="button"  id="b2" value="" name="b2" >
</div>
```

Here is : [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dtq38yvz/2/)

Comment: try using `!important` in `.bg1` class

Comment: Works on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/0wmao9ny/). Do you see the `alert()`? If not, you are not including the link to jQuery library.

Comment: Where is the image `info.jpg` loacted? Is it in the same directory as your .html file?

Comment: I have created Dynamic web Project in Eclipse Ide. Image is in WebInfo folder.Its in project folder itself. I gave full path of image but still not working

Comment: Then change `url(info.jpg)` to `url(WebInfo/info.jpg)`

Comment: @kavitag you mean the image is at root of the project.

Comment: Yes image is in project only. i tried giving full path of image but still not working

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working as intended after some modifications:

http://jsfiddle.net/dtq38yvz/7/

```
<div id="level_1" class="Level1"> 
    <input type="button" id="b2" value="" name="b2">
</div>

$('#b2').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("bg1");
});

#b2
{
    position:absolute;
    left:370px;
    top:130px;
    width:90px; /*same as the height*/
    height:90px;
    background-color:#fff;
}

.bg1
{
    background:url('http://i.ytimg.com/vi/UFS6Ky7OnAw/mqdefault.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing the jQuery library in your working example. I got it to work here: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dtq38yvz/5/) using

```
$('#b2').click(function(){
    alert("b2 am called"); 
    $(this).addClass("bg1");
});
```

and

```
input.bg1
{
    background:url('http://i.ytimg.com/vi/UFS6Ky7OnAw/mqdefault.jpg');
}
```

Complete solution:

```
<style>
   input#b2
{
position:absolute;
left:370px;
top:130px;
width:90px; /*same as the height*/
height:90px;
background:#fff;
}

input.bg1
{
    background:url('http://i.ytimg.com/vi/UFS6Ky7OnAw/mqdefault.jpg') !important;
} 
</style>

<div id="level_1"class="Level1"> 
    <input type="button"  id="b2" value="" name="b2" />
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $  = jQuery
    $('#b2').click(function(){
        alert("b2 am called"); 
        $(this).addClass("bg1");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Try adding `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>` before your javascript

Comment: I've added `!important` to the `background` value and it's fine now. I've updated my answer with the complete correct code.

Comment: I got the image. Thanks. why !important should be added?

Comment: This is because we added a white background to the input element by targeting its ID attribute but CSS styling hierarchy gives precedence to ID styles over class styles tso when we click the element and give it the .bg1 class it can't overwrite the styling already given to #b2. This JSFiddle demonstrates it well: http://jsfiddle.net/kL823x3p